# How to upload video to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, video

I am working on a PHP/CURL project that uploads videos to the various websites. Is there a way to post a video to the Facebook without creating an application? I found a way to update status info by posting to the Facebook Mobile version URLs but mobile version doesn't support video upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook will force you to create an application, any other way you might find today to upload video (and also what you did with the status update) is likely something that will break in the future again.

You're probably violating the ToS, and the status update thing could be considered a security hole.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I already figured that it's against the ToS and will have to create an application then. Now I am just curious of it's actually possible :)